# Move div with scroll at a specific position

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

I trying to do a small animation when an user reach a specific point of a page :

When the user scroll to 1000px (for example) I have a div called 'clouds' which need to move according to the scroll of the user.

If the user scroll down the clouds move left and if he scroll up the clouds move right.

I've tried this piece of code but unfortunately it doesn't work (the problem is that the div don't keep its position at start)

```
$(window).bind('scroll',function(e){
    parallaxScroll();
});

function parallaxScroll(){
    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('#cloud_left').css('left', parseInt(-scrolled / 5) + 'px');
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is might be a useful tutorial for you to read: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/05/lateral-on-scroll-sliding-with-jquery/

Comment: "...don't keep its position at start...," sorry, what?